# Class derivation and accessibility

Tags: c#, .net

I have this:

```
class Class1
{...}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
   public void myMethod(){};
}


var sth = new Class2();
```

Now, I want to do `sth.myMethod()`, but that method is inaccessible, why? How to fix that? (And i don't want to fix that by making `Class1` public)

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043121/derived-class-accessibility?rq=1) contains relevant information to your problem.

Comment: You will have to make the base class public if you want it's subclasses to be public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not allowed.  The compiler will give an error like:

> Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'YourNamespace.Class1' is less accessible than class 'YourNamespace.Class2'

You can't *inherit* from a class with a lower accessibility than the class you're exposing.

The best option in this type of scenario is to use composition instead of inheritance.

```
public class Class2
{
    private Class1 class1 = new Class1(); // Create an instance instead of inheriting...

    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
```